# pie chart label overlap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am having problems generating a graph which doesn't overlap with text both for percentages and country codes, I am using python3 matplotlib, see image below.

Any ways of fixing this issue even if it changes layout are appreciated.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
countries = []
import os

path = 'data_used_for_graph'

entries = os.listdir(path)
for file in entries:
    with open(path+"/"+file) as f:
        content = json.load(f)
        for x in content['personalNames']:
                countries.append(x['countryOrigin'])

counts = Counter(countries)

labels, values = zip(*counts.items())

# sort your values in descending order
indSort = np.argsort(values)[::-1]

# rearrange your data
labels = np.array(labels)[indSort]
values = np.array(values)[indSort]


# Data to plot
sizes = values

# Plot
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you mean "overlap" instead of "overflow". But I don't see a solution with a pie chart, you have way too many names. Maybe you could remove the text except for the largest 3 or 4 items?

Comment: Yup that's correct it's overlapping unfortunately removing most of the items will defeat the purpose of this pie chart :(

Comment: Try some interactive chart like this? https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/pie_chart.html